# Can someone explain to me what this error is and why it's deleting my cpp file?

Tags: c++

I am pretty sure I added the main file but I don't know why my cpp file is being deleted and why I am getting this error. I typed in the terminal
g++ -o assign8.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread

I would add my code but the file got deleted

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 20
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You set your output file (`-o _____`) to be your source file (`assign8.cpp`), so it overwrote it. Compilation then failed as it couldn't find the `main` function. Just set your output correctly, like `g++ -o assign8 assign8.cpp ...`.

Comment: Haha, this one strikes again. I bet it was shell tab completion. It happened to me in 1993. After that I *always* wrote a Makefile for compiling things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-o

you want to compile with something like: g++ -o assign8 assign8.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_thread
assign8.cpp is going to write to assign8.cpp, almost certainly not what you want. .cpp files are input not output.

Comment: oh okay thank you I'll try that out after I rewrite my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to use a Makefile in the future to help avoid this. Makefiles can be complicated but you'll need to learn all kinds of build systems if you want to do programming seriously.

The following goes into a file in the same directory as your source code. It has to be named `Makefile`. The capital M is traditional and I think it's necessary.

```
CFLAGS += -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic
CXXFLAGS = $(CFLAGS) -std=c++11
CFLAGS += -pthread
LDLIBS += -lboost_thread
LDFLAGS += -pthread

all: binary-file-read

test1: test1.o test2.o
```

You will want to tweak it. If you know about Makefiles you will notice I don't have any explicit build rules. It's relying on implicit rules.

Since "all" is the first target if I just type "make" it builds "all" which requires building "binary-file-read". There's a "binary-file-read.cpp" file which Make finds and figures out how to build using its implicit rules. Those rules use all the variables I defined.

Then "test1" builds from two object ".o" files. The directory has "test1.c" and "test2.c" and Make figures out how to build those into .o files then links them into an executable.

That directory also has a file named "opt-test.c" and I can type "make opt-test" and it builds it even though the Makefile doesn't mention it at all.

Make is really useful.